# Access Denied while accessing SharePoint Custom List Using Rest APIs via POSTMAN

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, office365apis

From couple of days, I am trying to access Custom made SharePoint Online **(Office 365)** List for CRUD Operation with the help of Rest APIs Endpoints using Postman, but all the time I am getting "Access Denied" Response in body.

I have got OAUTH Access Token with the help of Client Id, Client Secret, & Bearer Realm Token. I am also sending Access Token in Header, also i am given FULL-CONTROL Permission level by the SharePoint Admin.

Hope you got my point. Please let me know for any further Issue clarification.

**Note : List of Rest URL Endpoints I can Access are given below :**

```
http://YourSiteName.sharepoint.com/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos
http://YourSiteName.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists
```

**List of Rest URL End-Points I am not able to Access are :**

```
http://YourSiteName.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')
http://YourSiteName.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

Comment: To get List Items you dont need to pass FormDigestValue

Comment: i am getting using this URL siteUrl+"_api/lists/getbytitle('"+name+"')/items"

Comment: @VishalHalani I tried without FormDigestValue even though i got "Access Denied" in Response

Comment: are you doing in android?

Comment: @VishalHalani Not yet. But after getting successful response in POSTMAN i will try on Android App.

Comment: Actually i am developing mobile app through which we gonna access office 365 sharepoint custom list for CRUD operation.

Comment: hmm. ok..its work for me..i think its because you pass wrong credential or null

Answer (score 2):

I was not including site name in the URL.

```
http://YourSiteName.sharepoint.com/sites/**YOUR_Site_Name**/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')
```